# how to ignore a word to replace using regEx?

Tags: regex

```
<select class="form-control" name="work_status">
                          <option value="">Working With</option>
                          <option value="Private Company">Private Company</option>
                          <option value="Government/ Public sector">Government/Public Sector</option>
                           <option value="Government/ Public sector">Defense/Civil Services</option>
                             <option value="Government/ Public sector">Business/Self Employed</option>
                           <option value="Government/ Public sector">Not Working</option>
</select>
```

Here I want to remove all `<option value="Ignore this">`. This means I want to replace `<option value="">` with "" and `<option value="Private Company">` with "". I.e. I want to ignore word inside value attribute. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a language but for the regex part you can use this : `value="(.+)"`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xB1kV1/1)

Anyway you dont need Regex. You can do this with javascript. Let say you use jQuery:

```
$('.form-control option').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('value',"");
});
```